# Creating a Definition LIst with Variable-Width <dt> and <dd> (Includes JSFiddle)

Tags: html, css, layout, css-float

I have a definition list in which both term and definition are of varying widths.**[EDIT: To clarify, when I say varying widths, I mean that they must not be fixed width. Obviously, this effect is easily achieved by setting the width of the `']** I need each pair to sit side-by side, with the  becoming multi-line if necessary, without wrapping underneath the .

Here is a JSFiddle showing my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/2H9YN/ (Code below)

**[EDIT: Please note that the colours are for reference only. They are not significant to the final design]**

I currently have this:

[image]

But I want this:

[image]

HTML:

```
<dl>
    <dt>dt: Lorem Ipsum</dt>
    <dd>dd: Lorem imperdiet </dd>
    <dt>dt: Lorem id libero in Ipsum</dt>
    <dd>dd: Lorem id libero in ipsum dolor </dd>
    <dt>dt: Lorem Ipsum</dt>
    <dd>dd: I should be sitting to the right of the previous dt and not wrapping round below it.</dd>
    <dt>dt: Lorem id libero in Ipsum</dt>
    <dd>dd: Lorem in ipsum dolor </dd>
</dl>
```

CSS:

```
dl
{
    width:400px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    float: left;
}

dt
{
    clear:both;
    float:left;
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

dd
{
    float:left;
    background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.3);
    margin: 0 0 0 4px;
}
```

Essentially I am looking for the `<dd>` to fill the space left to it by the `<dt>`, and if this means it needs to wrap, that it wraps below itself, not below the adjacent `<dt>`.

Comment: Thank you for setting up the fiddle, made it so much easier to help you.

Comment: I love questions that provide demos *and* a visual representation of what they want <3

Comment: What about the case where `dt` is rather long and there is not enough room on the line for the `dd`?

Comment: Updated the fiddle...please review.

Comment: You need to specify a minimum amount of space for the `dd` element otherwise, it is hard to make this work.

Comment: I posted a new CSS based answer to your question.  Please take a look!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is some CSS that may work:

```
dl {
    width: 400px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    overflow: auto;
}

dt {
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3);
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    margin-right: 10px; /* Margin work */
    padding: 5px; /* Padding works */
}
dd {
    background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.3);
    display: table-cell;
    padding-left: 10px; /* Padding works */
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: 100px; /* Margin does not work */
    margin-bottom: 100px;
}
```

Fiddle reference: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/45jDK/

**Explanation of Why It Works**

(1) To see your background color, set `overflow: auto` for `dl`.  Since all the child elements are floated, the height collapses to zero by default.

(2) You want `dt` to start on a new line, so use `clear: left` so that `dt` does not try to flow after a short `dd` element.

(3) For `dd`, using `display: table-cell` seems to do the trick.

On `dt`, `padding` and `margin` work as expected.  On `dd`, `padding` works but `margin` has no effect, probably because of how `table-cell` works.

I tried this in Firefox but no where else.

**PS**
I added some extra content on one of the `dt` elements to see how an extreme situation would render.  I also experimented with the `width` of `dl` and the layout remains stable.

Comment: Thanks for taking a stab at it. However in my question, I mention that both the <dt> and <dd> need to be variable width. You've solved this by fixing the width of the <dd>, so unfortunately this is not the solution. I will clarify in my question.

Comment: The problem now is that if the <dt> is too long, it wraps to the next line. The point of my question is that the <dd> is liquid. It fills the space left by the <dt> without wrapping underneath the <ddt> if it is multiline. This new fiddle example is really just a variation on fixing the width. I appreciate your efforts.

Comment: I don't know how long `dt` can get, set its max-width to a reasonable value.

Comment: Let's say it a `<dt>` reach a maximum of 65%. Knowing this still doesn't help as you then need to set the `<dd>' to have a max-width of  35%. This is then no good for cases where the `<dt>` is short. The `<dd>` needs to fill the space left by the `<dt>`.

Comment: I will give a bit more thought.  Can I alter the mark-up or you constrained to this specific list layout?

Comment: It has to be a definition list.

Comment: Would you consider a jQuery based solution?

Comment: Nope. Pure CSS only please. That would be too easy ;)

Comment: Bravo. Excellent work. Works in everything back to and including IE8. Thanks a lot. Might just want to even out the padding between the dd and dt so they share a baseline if you are going to leave the fiddle up those that follow (please do).

Comment: Thank you, I did not think it was possible to do!  We are both wiser now.  All the best!

Comment: Cleaned up the padding so that the baselines match.  Demo is good to go.

Comment: No worries.You earned it ;) Would have given it to you sooner but had to wait 24 hours.

Answer (score 2):

The fact that you're using a definition list makes this very tricky to pull off.  Without some sort of container to enforce a relationship between the dt and dd, you have to set restrictions somewhere.

The closest I could get it with your markup works in Opera but not Chrome due to differences in Flexbox implementations:

http://jsfiddle.net/2H9YN/4/

```
dl {
  width: 400px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  float: left;
  display: -webkit-flexbox;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-flex-align: start;
  -ms-flex-align: start;
  -webkit-align-items: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

dt {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -webkit-flex: 0 0;
  -ms-flex: 0 0;
  flex: 0 0;
  white-space: pre;
}

dd {
  background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.3);
  margin: 0 0 0 4px;
  -webkit-flex: 1 1 50%;
  -ms-flex: 1 1 50%;
  flex: 1 1 50%;
}
```

And of course, only works if you never have more than 1 dd per dt.

If you're willing to change your markup so that you have some sort of row container, then you have more options.  It doesn't have to be a table, it can be a bunch of articles containing an h1 (dt) and a paragraph (dd).  The tags don't matter, just how the elements are grouped together.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>dt: Lorem Ipsum</th>
        <td>dd: Lorem imperdiet </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <th>dt: Lorem id libero in Ipsum</th>
        <td>dd: Lorem id libero in ipsum dolor </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <th>dt: Lorem Ipsum</th>
        <td>dd: I should be sitting to the right of the previous dt and not wrapping round below it.</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Again using Flexbox, we can get a perfect match right down to your grey background poking through when the elements don't have enough content to reach the end.  We can also get a reasonable fallback for non-Flexbox browsers:

http://jsfiddle.net/2H9YN/7/

```
table {
  width: 400px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

table, tbody, th, td {
  display: block;
}

tr {
  display: block;
  display: -webkit-flexbox;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-align: start;
  -ms-flex-align: start;
  -webkit-align-items: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

th, td {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: text-top;
}

th {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3);
  white-space: pre;
  font-weight: normal;
}

td {
  background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.3);
  margin: 0 0 0 4px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Your efforts are much appreciated. However, unfortunately I must use a definition list :( That's why I'm stuck.

Comment: The solution with flexbox doesn't work unless `dl` is set to some magic width value: next `dd` will show on the previous line as the third item: http://jsfiddle.net/2H9YN/20/