# How to create a definition list with equalized definition terms of variable length?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to create a definition list (with the help of [this guide](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)) with its `dt` and `dd` elements having different content. Ofcourse i could hardcode a width for these elements, but i'd like to have the list takes the longest `dt` element and make its siblings to have its length. Also, when the content of the `dd` element is longer than the available space the new line must not begin below the `dt` element but rather where the `dd` element begins like on the second screenshot in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15449114/1014412).

I thought i could solve this with the `display: flex` attribute but stuck with a non-working solution. Is it not possible or am a on the wrong way?

Here is what i've got so far [(fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/ncym6vym/):

HTML:

```
<dl>
   <dt>dt: Lorem Ipsum</dt>
   <dd>dd: Lorem imperdiet</dd>
   <dt>dt: Lorem id libero in Ipsum and so on and so on</dt>
   <dd>dd: Lorem id libero in ipsum dolor</dd>
   <dt>dt: Lorem Ipsum</dt>
   <dd>dd: I should be sitting to the right of the previous dt and not wrapping round below it.</dd>
   <dt>dt: Lorem id libero in Ipsum</dt>
   <dd>dd: Lorem in ipsum dolor</dd>
</dl>
```

CSS:

```
dl {
   display: flex;
   flex-flow: column nowrap;
}
dt {
   background: gold;
   display: flex;
   flex-flow: row wrap;
}
dd {
   background: yellowgreen;
   display: flex;
   flex-flow: row wrap;
   width: auto;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Can I add in wrappers and additional markup if I still use definition lists?

Comment: Give up and use tables

Comment: Duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/q/15449114/1014412

Comment: But I must agree with @Carol McKay: table is also semantical at this case. There is no need to try to create faux table using CSS. It's definitely a bad and dead practice to use them for page layout but you certainly can use them for data.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that it is possible to archive what you are trying. Flexbox won't help at this case. You also cannot use display table and so on, because the `dl` syntax unfortunately lacks wrapping of `dt+dd` groups. You would have to use JS to calc widths of the `dt` elements, but it wouldn't be also so easy because of multiline variants.

**But how about this a little bit modified "traditional" approach: make them min-width but allow the dt to overflow to the dd.**

```
dl:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
dt {
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  padding-top: 1em;
  margin-right: 1em;
}
dd {
  padding-top: 1em;
  margin-left: 15em;
}
```

http://codepen.io/ThiemelJiri/pen/KrZrxG

Answer (score 0):

I had a go with the DL:

https://jsfiddle.net/luminancedesign/0u0n39b9/

Uses :before / :after blocks for background striping - best with solid colour to avoid 'inline' shape outlining, e.g.

```
dt:nth-of-type(even) {background: silver;}
dd:nth-of-type(odd) {background: slategrey;}
```

and:

```
dt:nth-of-type(even)::after {... background: darkgrey;}
dd:nth-of-type(odd)::before {... background: lightslategrey;}
```

I've used a width limit, to keep some 'aesthetic' to the display - having irregular blocks doesn't make for clear reading. However this is leading into tablular data layout and as mentioned above, a table may be more appropriate.